# Searching for words in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search

Despite the fact that there is no `ctrl`+`f` feature to search in Outlook, and instead you must use `ctrl`+`e`, I still cannot seem to find any method to search contents of an individual email. `ctrl`+`e` only allows you to search a folder, as far as I can see.

i.e. **I am looking for a string in one specific email**, I am not trying to find an email by a string.

It's pretty important to be able for me to do this, because I am constantly getting emails with long lists of CC, and being able to perform a standard search for text on the currently displayed email would be a huge timesaver.

As it is now, I have to copy and paste the entire email into some kind of word pad and do `ctrl`+`f` to see if someone's name is already there or if I should forward the message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT:

You can use the `Search` function from the ribbon within an e-mail:
[image: Find Button]

This will find text within an e-mail.

---

In the upper-right of your inbox, there is a search box.  This box searches all e-mails and their contents (minus attachments).

There is also a search tab that you can enable.

[More information here](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/03/01/better-searching-in-outlook-2010.aspx).

[image: search ribbon]

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves see edit.

Comment: So, the trick is to double click the email and open it into its own window? How inconvenient! But this works! Marking as solved.

Comment: Yeah, not many tools exist for the reading pane to do what you wanted.  It's more of a preview to aid in a quick-find a specific e-mail.

Answer (score 6):

1. Double click to open the email.
2. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the search box, and search the contents of *this* email.

PS: I haven't been able to figure out a way to fire up such a search without opening the email. Yes, a huge inconvenience, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the body of emails using the "Body" section of the search in Outlook.  Attached is a screen shot of where you would search for text in the body of an email.[image: Outlook Search]

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean that I am looking for messages with certain information in it, I am looking for certain information in one specific email.

Answer (score 2):

To search for a singular WORD or TEXT STRING among the contents of a specific email in MS Outlook 2010:

1. Open the email
2. On the ribbon menu at the top of the email you will find an icon that looks like a little pair of binoculars with the word "Find" just to the right of it.
3. Click that "Find" icon and a small, wonderfully useful window entitled "Find and Replace" will appear.  This provides all the options you'll need to quickly locate the WORD or TEXT STRING you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better way then I could find elsewhere.
This is for finding text in an email currently being previewed in the preview pane.
Make a macro that opens the email and then brings up the find text dialog.

```
Sub FindText()
  SendKeys "^o{F4}"
End Sub
```

Then assign this macro to the ribbon wherever you find it most helpful.
I add it to the quick access toolbar and in its own group on the home tab.
Sadly, I have found no way to make this fire with a keyboard shorcut.